# do some action when order status is changed to complete

Tags: 7, commerce, rules

In drupal commerce I want the rules module to do some action when the order status changes to `completed`. In fact, after buying some product an order is added to order list. Then, what I need is that when the moderator comes and change the order status to `completed` the order owner get permission to see some content type.

I have tested these rules but none of them worked!!

- Event: After updating an existing commerce order
- Condition: Execute custom PHP code

  ```
  if([commerce-order:status] == 'completed') return TRUE;
  else return FALSE;
  ```

or this one:

- Event: After updating an existing commerce order
- Condition: Data comparison

  ```
  Parameter: Data to compare: [commerce-order:status], Data value: Completed
  ```

or this one:

- Event: After updating an existing commerce order
- Condition: Data comparison

  ```
  Parameter: Data to compare: [commerce-order:state], Data value: Completed
  ```

In fact, without adding any condition the reaction is done after adding an order by customers (do not wait for moderators to complete the order) and with any of these conditions, rules never fire and the is reaction never done.

Comment: _In fact, without adding any condition the reaction is done after adding an order by customers_ That is to be expected, in that case the rule fires every time the order is updated. Both status and state checks look good. Strange they don't work.

Comment: @Neograph734 yes that's strange. Any other idea?

Comment: check recent log messages [admin/reports/dblog]. Maybe there is an issue with the action that you're trying to fire. You can add [Show a message on the site] as an action, to test if event with condition can trigger anything at all.

Comment: what do you mean by "test if event with condition can trigger anything at all" ?  I add reaction of "show a message on the site" and printed the value of order state and order status. that was OK

Comment: Did that also work combined with the data comparison condition?

Comment: @shekoufeh if you are able to trigger a system message while having a condition (order status = completed), than your Rule works. This means that the assignment of permission fails - not the Rule logic. How are you assigning the permission to the order:owner? by giving a new role?

Comment: @oksana-c yes the reaction is "add user a role" and the target user is "site:current-cart-order:owner". Reaction works without any condition!!

Comment: @Neograph734 comparison condition does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the details provided by you in comments, your rule is assigning new role to the user who is currently editing the order `[site:current-cart-order:owner]`.

You need to use `[commerce-order:owner]` token in `"Add User Role"` action.

*`[commerce-order:owner]` represents the user who created the order, and not the user who is editing it.*

Answer (score 0):

Given below is the example rule to update user role on order status update:

```
{ "rules_update_user_role_on_order_complete" : {
    "LABEL" : "Update user role on order complete",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "TAGS" : [ "order" ],
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "entity" ],
    "ON" : { "commerce_order_update" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "data_is" : { "data" : [ "commerce-order:status" ], "value" : "completed" } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "user_add_role" : {
          "account" : [ "commerce-order:owner" ],
          "roles" : { "value" : { "3" : "3" } }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here you need to change the user role of the order owner in action.